# How can I get the total resources (vCPU, RAM) allocated to a Kubernetes cluster via GKE API (python)?

Tags: python, api, google-kubernetes-engine, metrics

I'm trying to write a Python script that would poll data using GKE API. However, I don't see the total vCPU or total memory when I send the request to get data on the clusters. The same information is available on the main page of the Google cloud console's overview tab. Currently, I don't care about the requested resources, just the available maximum.
Please let me know if this is something I simply can't find or is impossible to automate this way on Google Cloud Functions.

Thank you!

Comment: The GUI performs a query on all the nodes and show it as an aggregated value. If the Kubernetes API doesn't have a way to that than your option is to query all the nodes, get the available vCPU and memory and sum them up

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem for me to iterate through the clusters and get info on the node pools (and nodes if that's really necessary), but I don't see that option either. (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest)

Comment: What about this API https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/NodeConfig

Comment: As I see, it gets returned as part of the response when I poll the cluster info, however, I only see the "machineType" like "n2-standard-4". I'd need to maintain a dictionary to get the current vCPU and RAM Google provides. As I said if there's an option to retrieve the resources one by one, I'd be okay with that but I don't see any option to get that info with the API.

Comment: I don't think we have an API for that. I think the only practical way is to keep an dictionary of the machine-type to config mapping.

Comment: Thank you. I'll iterate through the instances using the 'kubernetes' Python package.

Comment: @boredabdel One more question if you could help me out with. I'm trying to gather data that's available on the "Workloads" page. To be more precise, I'd like to count the types (deployment/stateful set/replica set) by status and the pod count. Do you know where can I get that info? 
Thank you!